# how to apply class "active" in hyperlink codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, codeigniter

I have divided my template into three parts consisting of header, footer and content. 
Main menu links are in header file... So I want to apply a CSS class 'active' to hyperlink which is selected... I have written jquery code too which is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#emp').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
  });

</script>
```

The problem of this code is whenever I click on the link, it attaches the CSS class and then removes it.

Comment: Could you prepare jsFiddle with an example of that?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek http://jsfiddle.net/3K4TP/  check here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whenever i click on the link it attaches the css class and then removes it...

`addClass` doesn't remove the class, it seems your page is reloaded. Prevent the default action of the event:

```
$('#emp').click(function(eventObject) {
    eventObject.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Update:

When you click on your `<a>` element the page is redirected and your added classes is removed, if you want to add the class using JavaScript you can code:

```
// relative
var path = document.location.pathname;
// absolute
var path = document.location.href;

$('#myMenu a').filter(function(){
    return this.href === path;
}).closest('li').addClass('active');

// Or:
$('#myMenu li').has('a[href='+path+']').addClass('active');
```

Comment: @mynameisjohn JavaScript can't change the classes on other pages, you should use PHP and add the classes on server-side.

Comment: @mynameisjohn Use it's [`uri`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) class to find the current page `url` and then set it to your `view`.

Comment: ...ok i used the uri segment and get the specific page name .. now what is the next step .. i pass it to the view also ...

Comment: @mynameisjohn Great, it depends on your `viwe` logic, I have updated the answer, please try it and let me know the result.

Comment: thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk youuuuuu .. it works .. you are genious

Answer (score -1):

I Use this method to slove this type of problem

```
<?php $self= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>

<ul class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">

     <li <?php
     if (eregi("index", $self))
        echo "class=\"selected\"";
     ?>><a href="index" >HOME</a>
    </li>

    <li><img  style="height:28px" src="images/newsletter-divider.gif" alt="Divider"/></li>

     <li
     <?php
     if (eregi("logout", $self))
        echo "class=\"selected\"";
     ?>
     ><a href="logout">Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```